# move_uploaded_file is returning false

Tags: php, file-upload

Hello I'm working on a webshop for school and I want the user to upload a product to a slider. The data is saved in a database and the photos are uploaded in a file on my server. The upload to the database works but the upload to the file is not. Permissions are all set to 777 so that's not it. The errors are also saying nothing so I really don't know why it is not working.

I would really like your help :)

```
<?php
$target_dir = "admin/upload/".$_POST['tab']."/";
// $target_dir ="/domains/i310033.iris.fhict.nl/public_html/SmokeStik/admin/upload/".$_POST['tab']."/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 1000000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}

include 'connection.php';

$titel = $_POST['titel'];
$imagelink = $target_dir.$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$omschrijving = $_POST['content'];
$prijs = $_POST['prijs'];
$tab = $_POST['tab'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO $tab (titel, imagelink, omschrijving, prijs, tab)
VALUES ('$titel', '$imagelink', '$omschrijving', '$prijs', '$tab')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
echo $imagelink;
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: The errors may "say nothing" to you, but unless you tell us what they are we'd just be guessing.

Comment: Please check error log

Comment: File is an image - image/jpeg.Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.Connected successfullyNew record created successfully

Comment: First of all you wouldn't want to create the database entry unless the image upload was successful. And the error messages you have set are not helpful. Turn on PHP Errors to see what's going on!

Comment: yes i know but i only was testing. I've set PHP errors on but i didn't get any errors still the same as first

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use 'tmp_name' instead of 'name'

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)`

Comment: according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php, could you please make sure that you called the uploaded file correctly? for example, try print $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] before move_uploaded_file